# Pure AS3 Project with onInvoke working

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm trying to create a pure ActionScript 3 AIR project, **without** Flex, somewhat like in the following question:

[ActionScript Project to AIR Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966180/actionscript-project-to-air-application)

...but I'm not really sure how to access command line arguments from onInvoke(). I need this for accessing command line arguments for my Pure AS3 AIR application.

Here's my source code:

```
public class Doclet extends Sprite
{
    public function Doclet()
    {
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, onInvoke);

        var win:NativeWindow = new NativeWindow(new NativeWindowInitOptions());
        win.activate();
        win.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, function():void
        {
            NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit(0);
        });

        win.stage.addChild(this);

        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
    }

    private function onInvoke(event:InvokeEvent):void
    {
        trace('Invoke...');
    }
}
```

Imports omitted for brevity. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example from my code about how to do this:

//in my mxml WindowedApplication description:

```
<mx:WindowedApplication
    backgroundColor="0xFFFFFF"
    backgroundGradientColors="[0xFFFFFF, 0x93BBFF]"
    backgroundGradientAlphas="[0.5, 1]"
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    layout="absolute"
    initialize="initEvent(event)"
    >
```

//code that needs to go inside the script area of the mxml for this application

```
//                   initialization
private function initEvent(event:Event):void{
                NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, onInvokeEvent);
                NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(BrowserInvokeEvent.BROWSER_INVOKE,onBrowserInvoke);
            //  Alert.show(NativeApplication.nativeApplication.publisherID);
            }
```

//Ran when program is invoked (can run more than once)

```
        private function onInvokeEvent(event:InvokeEvent):void{
            trace("in onInvoke function");

            ++invokeCounter;


            if(event.arguments.length != 0){
                args = event.arguments.join(",");
            }else{//do nothing
            }
            firstInvoke = false;

        }
```

Also see [adobe help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.1/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a5d46-8000.html) for a more full description.

Comment: Just added some source code, please keep in mind, I don't have a MXML file, my AIR app is starting up from Doclet.as :)

Comment: Just got it to work, I dunno what was out of place...but:
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, onInvokeEvent);

solved my issue. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: no prob, I recall struggling with reading arguments from a browser invocation.  It looks like the documentation is much more mature now (either that or I understand it better)